# Sorting with a custom method with additional parameter?

Tags: python, sorting

So I have a fitness function (returning only true or false for a given pair of arguments) which I would like to use as a key for sorting my list of possible arguments. While normally, I'd be able to do something like:

```
sorted(possibleArguments, key = fitnessFunction)
```

Here the probles is that my fitness function looks like this:

```
def fitnessFunction(arg1, arg2, f):
    return f(*arg1) < f(*arg2)
```

Of course in the method I want to use the sorting, the function using which the fitness is to be calculated is known and doesn't change during the sorting but can I somehow tell Python that's the case? Can I do something like:

```
sorted(possibleArguments, key = fitnessFunction(one element to be compared, the other one, function I'm currently interested in))
```

If so, how?

Comment: Are `arg1` and `arg2` objects of the same type? If so, you can write the `__gt__`, `__lt__`, and `__eq__` functions in that class to do the comparisons.

Comment: @Brobin yep, they're simple tuples of the same number of floats each

Comment: Hmm, if you wrap it in a class, you can use those methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`key` does not take a comparison function, it converts an element of the list into a comparable item.

BTW It's no longer possible to pass a comparison function to `sort` in python 3 (and the `__cmp__` method is gone from objects too), so you better get used to it (it was cumbersome, you had to return 0 if equal, negative if lesser, positive if bigger, a bit like `strcmp` does, archaic. You could create complex comparison functions, but they could reveal unstable. I surely don't miss them).

Fortunately you have the `f()` function which is enough.

You just have to do this in your case:

```
sorted(possibleArguments, key = lambda x : f(*x))
```

the comparisons are done by the `sort` function. No need for `fitnessFunction`